# Count nested objects no more than once in each document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with documents of the following structure:

```
{
  "_id" : "1234567890abcdef",
  ...
  "entities" : [
    {  
      "name" : "beer",
      "evidence_start" : 12,
      "evidence_end" : 16
    },
    {  
      "name" : "water",
      "evidence_start" : 55,
      "evidence_end" : 60
    },
    {  
      "name" : "beer",
      "evidence_start" : 123,
      "evidence_end" : 127
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

`entities` is an object of type `nested` here. I need to count how many documents contain mentions about beer.
The issue is that an obvious bucket aggregation returns the amount of mentions, not documents, so that if `beer` is mentioned twice in the same document, it adds up 2 to the total result as well.
A query I use to do that is:

```
{
  ...
  "aggs": {
      "entities": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "entities"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "entity_count": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "entities.name",
              "size" : 20
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ...
}
```

Is there a way of counting only distinct mentions without scripting?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need to a [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) as a sub aggregation, to count the number of "main documentd" instead of nested documents.

You should try

```
{
  ...
  "aggs": {
      "entities": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "entities"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "entity_count": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "entities.name",
              "size" : 20
            },
            "aggs": {
                "main_document_count": {
                    "reverse_nested": {}
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ...
}
```